# jQuery Multiple Functions Radio Button

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this has been asked before, searching for days now and haven't coded in 10+ years.

I try to highlight the first radio button for shipment-method (this works fine) but also for payment_method. I do this with a seperate .js file cause I can't access the checkout page at all.

You can see them both here:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Payment source code:

```
                <div id="gui-block-payment-method" class="gui-section gui-block gui-step gui-validate step-payment gui-inactive " data-name="payment" data-error="Selecteer een betaalmethode.">
                    <div class="gui-block-subtitle gui-bigger">Betaalmethoden</div>
```

Shipment is similar except there is no data refresh:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[name=shipment_method]").click(function(){

  setTimeout(function() {

        $("#gui-shipment-method").prop("checked",true) },1500);

  })

  $("input[name=shipment_method]").first().click()

})
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? HTML elements select by default when you click on them.

Comment: Sorry. I have a checkout page on my shop which I cannot access so I made a seperate js file. I'm trying to get the 1st radio highlighted here for the "Betaalmethoden" (payment_method) as well as "Verzendmethode" (shipment_method): https://i.gyazo.com/ac7bc2315518f7b270c39f55c8982176.png

Comment: what do you mean with *but also for payment_method* .. in a same `click` event or make another click event??

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to explain it better in the comment above. I don't know if I need another one or not but I tried so many methods I forgot which ones.

Comment: can you provide the html code??

Comment: I don't even know how it works exactly, as it's a framework I'm completely new with. There are no php or html files and I can't access the page source, I have a link to the checkout css page but can't edit it though. I figured I just needed to add another click function for payment_method but don't know how : https://static.webshopapp.com/assets/checkout/checkout.css?2017-04-26?10

Comment: open your browser console and copy/paste the related rendered html code

Comment: Not sure if I'm allowed to link my site but well.. you can check it here: https://www.vapenu.nl/element-pink-lemonade-e-liquid.html

Press the big green buttons and you arrive at the checkout page.. thanks for the replies by the way.

Comment: Don't have just a  regular html code.. just mumbo jumbo everywhere.

<div id="gui-block-payment-method" class="gui-section gui-block gui-step gui-validate step-payment gui-inactive " data-name="payment" data-error="Selecteer een betaalmethode.">
                        <div class="gui-block-subtitle gui-bigger">Betaalmethoden</div>

<div id="gui-form-payment-method" class="gui-block-subcontent">
  <div id="gui-checkout-payment-methods" data-refresh="me">

Answer (score 0):

You can Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=shipment_method]").click(function(){
       setTimeout(function() {
          $("#gui-shipment-method , #gui-payment-seoshoppayments-ideal").prop("checked",true) 
       },1500);
    }).first().click();
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=shipment_method]").click(function(){
       setTimeout(function() {
           $("#gui-shipment-method").prop("checked",true);
           $("#gui-payment-seoshoppayments-ideal").change();
       },1500);
    }).first().click();
 })
```

While you have this `<script>` in your code

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="shipment_method"], input[name="payment_method"]', function()
  {
    var section = $(this).parents('.gui-section');
    var parent  = $(this).parents('[data-method]');

    $(section).find('[data-subform]').hide();

    parent.find('[data-subform]').show();
});
```

instead of your attempting code you can just use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=shipment_method] , input[name=payment_method]").first().change();
    // OR
    $("input[name=shipment_method] , input[name=payment_method]").first().prop("checked" , true).change();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work unfortunately: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: @Samir sorry I have a bad internet connection .. try both codes above .. I believe one of those will work with you

Comment: It actually removed the shipment function as well, I'm pretty sure it has to be shipment_method so I assume also payment_method

Comment: I only tried the first one.

2nd one works, thank you so much! It works almost perfect except the payment method one isn't actually selected, a "choose your bank" option becomes available, which normally only happens after selecting it. However even after choosing bank it says "please  select payment method" when I try to complete payment.  Then I click the radio button and it works: https://i.gyazo.com/35f790676a4c40956e0ba249b3679535.png

Comment: @Samir if `.first().change();` dosen't work .. you can try `.first().trigger('change');`  or `.eq(0).change()`

Comment: The trigger disabled it, the eq same  as normal. I will try the other codes you posted above, I'll go get some sleep, thanks so much for your help. If ther eis a donate button or something show me that as well :)

Comment: @Samir You're welcome .. no Donate button .. have a sweet dreams :-)

Comment: Oh wow thank you thank you. Appearantly I inserted common.js twice on 2 pages by accident, removed it and this works great:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=shipment_method]").click(function(){
       setTimeout(function() {
           $("#gui-shipment-method").prop("checked",true);
           $("#gui-payment-seoshoppayments-ideal").change();
       },1500);
    }).first().click();
 })
Works like a charm. If you need some small work let me know.. ;)